# Can not run index.html in oracle Jet application using templates

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans, oracle-jet

I am new to Oracle Jet. Now I want to use NetBeans to create a simple application with pre-defined templates downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jet/downloads/index.html.

The creation steps are:
file - new project - Categories (HTML5/JavaScript) and Projects (HTML5/JS Application) -select the template - Jet-Template Web Basic.zip. 
But when I open index.html under Site Root in this application, the "Run" tab is not available. Also there is no "run" when right click on index.html.

I tried all other templates in the download page but none of them can work.

Do you have an idea on this?

IDE version: NetBeans 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why that happens. Might be a bug...

2 work-arounds:

1. Right-click on the project under the Projects tab. You'll notice the Run function is enabled here.
2. **(Better option)** Extract the zip contents, choose 'Open Project' in Netbeans and navigate to the extracted folder. You'll notice that the Run function is available for index.html if you open the project this way.